# Connect to php page using .htaccess with android application

Tags: php, android, .htaccess, connection

i've a locked php page  (username and password) by .htaccess file, how can i do to connect to this php with my android application? My function to connect is :

```
String conn(JSONObject json,String page){
        String result = "";
         String stringaFinale = "";
         InputStream is = null;

         final int TIMEOUT_MILLISEC = 5000;  // = 10 seconds    
        HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);

        HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://olbolb.org/Hihi/"+page);

        //request result type
        request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

      try{  StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());
           se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json"));
           request.setEntity(se);      

           HttpResponse response = client.execute(request); 

            temp= EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            return temp;

      }
      catch(Exception e){ 
          return null; 

      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this code for BASIC authentication in `HttpPost` object:

```
HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://olbolb.org/Hihi/"+page);
request.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + 
   new Base64().encodeToString("username:password".getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.DEFAULT) );
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but Base64Encoder gives me an error...what is it?

Comment: You can use any available BASE64 package and call it's encode method.

Comment: Using Apache's common's BASE64 you can do: `new Base64().encodeToString("username:password".getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.DEFAULT)`

Comment: request.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encode (("username:password").getBytes("UTF-8"),Base64.DEFAULT)); doesn't work

Comment: maybe it's not UTF-8?

Comment: when you say doesn't work, what error are you getting?

Comment: it seems that the json doesn't arrive to php,  i've replaced you header with my old header written in the  post, is it right?

Comment: Base64.URL_SAFE|Base64.NO_WRAP) with this it works, thanks btw.