# Connect to php .htaccess with my application

Tags: java, android, .htaccess, http-post

I've a locked php page (username and password) by .htaccess file.
I try to connect to this php with my android application.

I try this page here : [Connect to php page using .htaccess with android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22462890/connect-to-php-page-using-htaccess-with-android-application)

But it doesn't work..

My code :

```
HttpClient cnxHttp = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost paramCnx = new HttpPost(strings[0]);
paramCnx.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " +  new Base64().encodeToString("user:mdp".getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.DEFAULT));
```

I get an error en getBytes : UnsupportedEncodingException.
I don't understand why, can somoene explain to me and give me the right code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it.
Answer :

```
String authorizationString = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(
                    ("your_login" + ":" + "your_password").getBytes(),
                    Base64.NO_WRAP); //Base64.NO_WRAP flag
            post.setHeader("Authorization", authorizationString);
```